# Regular Expression for Financial Numbers

Tags: python, regex

I think my chances are slim based on the responses to other questions related to regular expressions.

I am try to parse numbers in different representations:

```
12345(234567)
12345(234.56K)
```

from which I cannot control the source format.

I suppose I can come up with different regular expression for different formats. How to detect which format is which? Has it to be brute-force way to look for the letter 'K'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of thing is often done by iterating over a bunch of regular expressions and stopping when you find one that matches - because your conversion from a string to a number needs special parsing beyond the capabilities of regular expressions. That means you need to order them in a way that you know will give the right answer. In this case, you might do something like this:

```
PARSERS = (
    (re.compile(r'([0-9]+)\(([-+0-9.]+)[mM]\)'), 1000000),
    (re.compile(r'([0-9]+)\(([-+0-9.]+)[kK]\)'), 1000),
    (re.compile(r'([0-9]+)\(([-+0-9.]+)\)'), 1),
)

def parse(num):
    for pattern, multiplier in PARSERS:
        match = pattern.match(num)
        if match is not None:
            return float(match.group(1)), float(match.group(2)) * multiplier
    raise ValueError("Failed to parse")
```

As an aside, this pattern is common in other places too, such as deciding [which function will handle a web request](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/structure.html#the-application-object) based on the URL.

Just for fun, here's an alternative implementation that uses dictionary lookups and a single regular expression instead of iteration:

```
MULTIPLIER = {
    'M': 1000000,
    'K': 1000,
    '': 1,
}
PATTERN = re.compile(r'(\d+)\(([-+.\d]+)([kKmM]?)\)')

def parse(num):
    match = PATTERN.match(num)
    if match is None:
        raise ValueError("Failed to parse")
    first, second, suffix = match.groups()
    suffix = suffix.upper()
    if suffix not in MULTIPLIER:
        raise ValueError("Unrecognised multiplier %s" % suffix)
    return float(first), float(second) * MULTIPLIER[suffix]
```

Comment: `([0-9])+` will only capture the last digit. Use `([0-9]+)`. Also `[0-9]` can be replaced with `\d`.

Comment: @z0r: thanks! just that I thought chances are slim to have any response!

Comment: @Alex: Thanks for the bug fix. I'm not sure about using `\d` though: in Python [`float()`expects digits `"0"..."9"`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#floating), while `\d` will match other characters [outside that range](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

Comment: @chapter3 I added a second option that only uses one expression